# Write generic method which takes enum and string as arguments

Tags: java, generics, java-8, enums

Please suggest. Suppose I have two enums as shown below. I'm performing tasks if enum values match my string.

```
public enum Action {
        DO("DO"),
        REDO("REDO"),
        ROLLBACK("DONT");

        private String value;

        private Action(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

public enum Days {
        WEEK("WORK"),
        LEAVE("DONT WORK");

        private String value;

        private Days(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
```

And I want below work to be generic for both cases:

```
//any String 
String sp ="do";

        Arrays.stream(Action.values()).forEach(e ->{
            if(e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(sp)){
                //System.out.println(sp); Some work to do here

            }
        } );
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "generic"? How would you want to call the generic method?

Comment: @Sweeper For example: I want to check if enum value matches my string I want to return or print the enum's name/value or return true at least, for that I don't want to write same lines of codes for each enums. Please correct/ suggest me if I'm wrong (being new to java) is there any way like I could write a method like we do for objects: `public  static <T> void   myFunc(T myObject){
        // do something
        return;
    }`

Comment: @alwaysabeginner So, you are expecting T to be either Action or Days?

Comment: for anything to be generic amongst two types, the first pre-requisite is to make sure that they derive from the same hierarchy!

Comment: @CommanderTvis Can be anyother enums too implemented in similar manner. thanks

Comment: @Naman yes agreed. That's why Generics for Objects are easy to write. For the first time I was working on enums and there were multiple lines of codes with the same work being repeated. So for this scenario is there any other way to reduce redundant code might not be generic method, Please suggest any ideas, as suggested by **@Sweeper** is a good approach, since it belongs to external jar, can not follow that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need from both enums in this code:

```
    Arrays.stream(Action.values()).forEach(e ->{
        if(e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(sp)){
            //System.out.println(sp); Some work to do here

        }
    } );
```

is the `getValue` method.

So you can create an interface that has this method:

```
interface HasValue {
    String getValue();
}
```

Make both enums implement the interface:

```
public enum Action implements HasValue {
    ...
}

public enum Days implements HasValue {
    ...
}
```

Then you can write a generic method:

```
public <T extends HasValue> void foo(T[] values, String sp) {
    Arrays.stream(values).forEach(e ->{
        if(e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(sp)){
            //System.out.println(sp);

        }
    });
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
foo(Action.values(), sp);
foo(Days.values(), sp);
```

The method doesn't actually have to be generic. You could just do:

```
public void foo(HasValue[] values, String sp) {
    ...
}
```

If you can't change `Days` or `Action`, you can use a functional interface instead:

```
public <T> void foo(T[] values, Function<T, String> getValue, String sp) {
    Arrays.stream(values).forEach(e ->{
        if(getValue.apply(e).equalsIgnoreCase(sp)){
            //System.out.println(sp);

        }
    });
}

// usage:

foo(Action.values(), Action::getValue, sp);
foo(Days.values(), Days::getValue, sp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but enum I'm referring is part of an external jar and cannot be changed/modified.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. I might have used the incorrect question title.

Comment: You could also refactor out the `.values()`, and have the method take `Class<T>` where `<T extends Enum<T>>`, and inside the method call `.getEnumConstants()` to get the values, though I guess that wouldn't simplify it that much.